# Firebase Storage files not downloading. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to download a file that has been uploaded to Firebase Storage. I used to get the CORS error but I used gsutil as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) and now nothing really happens. The download doesn't start. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Create reference of Storage
    let storage = firebase.storage();

    //Create reference to file in Storage
    let pathSubmission = 'Uploads/' + this.place1+ '/' + this.place2+ '/' + this.place3+ '/' + this.downloadSubmissionUID;

    let storageRef = storage.ref(pathSubmission);

    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {

      console.log('downloadURL arg: ' + url);

      //Download file (no idea how this works)
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        var blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out using [Kai's blog](https://ausdemmaschinenraum.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-save-a-file-from-a-url-with-javascript/), here's my solution:

```
    //Create reference of Storage
    let storage = firebase.storage();

    //Create reference to file in Storage
    let pathSubmission = 'Uploads/' + this.place1 + '/' + this.place2+ '/' + this.place3 + '/' + this.downloadSubmissionUID;

    //Assign Storage reference the path reference
    let storageRef = storage.ref(pathSubmission);

    //Download file by creating XMLHttpRequest
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        //Create an `a` tag (since it has an `href` and a `download` attribute) 
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        a.download = 'someFileName';
        a.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();                            //Simulates a click event
        var blob = xhr.response;
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the file is probably getting downloaded. The problem is in this code here:

```
//Download file (no idea how this works)
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(event) {
  var blob = xhr.response;
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.send();
```

The browser is doing exactly what it's told. It downloads the file as a blob. Then discards the result, because you aren't doing anything with the data in the `onload` handler!

First, I'd recommend using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which provides a much more intuitive API than the `XMLHttpRequest` (in my opinion).

Here's how you might do that:

```
// Create reference of Storage
let storage = firebase.storage();

// Create reference to file in Storage
let pathSubmission = 'Uploads/' + this.place1+ '/' + this.place2+ '/' + this.place3+ '/' + this.downloadSubmissionUID;

let storageRef = storage.ref(pathSubmission);

storageRef.getDownloadURL()
  .then(url => {
    console.log('Download URL: ' + url)
    return fetch(url)
  })
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    console.log('File downloaded as blob')
    // Do something with the blob...
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Something went wrong while downloading the file:', error)
  })
```

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the `'File downloaded as blob'` logged, now how exactly do I download the file?

Comment: "*now how exactly do I download the file*" When you see that message in the console, the file has already been downloaded. You need to do something with the `blob`. Or it can be interpreted as `json`, or `text` (string), or an `ArrayBuffer`, using the fetch API. I assume you know which of these is appropriate and how to use them. If not, there are a number of tutorials that explain how to use each of these.

Comment: That's what this question is about --> How do I actually _download_ the file? I didn't need to use the fetch API. I'm still at square one.